# Get batch script exitCode with ExecDos Plugin from NSIS

Tags: batch-file, nsis, exit-code

How do I get the exitCode from a batch file (as well as the output written to the DetailView window)?

From the [documention](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in):

> Use 'wait' call if you want to get exit code. (/NOUNLOAD is mandatory!)

So something like this:

```
ExecDos::wait /NOUNLOAD /DETAILED "$INSTDIR\bin\checkJavaVersion.bat"
```

(I haven't dealt with specifying which window to output to yet)

How do I access the exitCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first `exec` and then you `wait`. `wait` does not start the process so you cannot pass the command line to it. The documentation you linked to has an example:

```
ExecDos::exec /NOUNLOAD /ASYNC "$EXEDIR\consApp.exe" "test_login$\ntest_pwd$\n" "$EXEDIR\execdos.log"
Pop $0 # thread handle for wait
# you can add some installation code here to execute while application is running.
ExecDos::wait $0
Pop $1 # return value
MessageBox MB_OK "Exit code $1"
```